# Как убрать со списка элементы после определенного?

Tags: c#, list

Есть список

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>(){"киев","москва","токио","БЕРЛИН","тегеран"};
```

Как убрать из него элементы которые идут после элемента, у которого все символы заглавные. Т.е. убрать `БЕРЛИН`(так как у него все буквы заглавные) и `тегеран`

Я знаю как сделать сравнение - а не все ли символы в строки заглавные?

```
lst.Where(x=>x.IsUpper()==x)...
```

Однако не совсем понятно как удалять этот и последующий элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Where` здесь не очень подходить так как возвращает "список"`(IEnumerable<string>)` результатов, лучше использовать `First`:

```
int index = lst.IndexOf(lst.First(x=>x.IsUpper()==x));
```

А еще лучше сделать так

```
int index = lst.FindIndex(x=>x.IsUpper()==x);
```

Так как нам нужен индекс, а не сам элемент списка. Ну и удаление:

```
if (index > -1)  { lst.RemoveRange(index, lst.Count - index);  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать метод `TakeWhile` - он выбирает все элементы, пока не сработает условие.

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "киев", "москва", "токио", "БЕРЛИН", "тегеран" };

lst = lst.TakeWhile(s => s.ToUpper() != s).ToList();
```